# nginx 403 Forbidden on laravel project with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-config

When I start de Project with `php artisan serve` everything works fine, but when I start my project with `docker-compose up -d` there is an error: **403 Forbidden nginx/1.10.3**

Nginx default file:

```
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name {{getenv "NGINX_SERVER_NAME"}};

    server_tokens off;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    add_header X-Served-By Bitpress.io;
    include h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

and here is my **docker-compose** File

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    image: test
    container_name: site
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-tier
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      APP_ENV: local
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app

  scheduler:
    image: test
    container_name: scheduler
    depends_on:
      - app
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: scheduler

  queue:
    image: test
    container_name: queue
    depends_on:
      - app
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: queue
```

I've seen, that the Permissions from the Directories is root.
I have tried to change it with the command`RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html` but it not works.

Comment: can you provide the docker-compose.yml

Comment: added the compose File :)

Answer (score 0):

I just update what you have, but won't fix 100% your issues, some stuff have ot be done too, but without all information I cannot do more.
You may need to add php-fpm into your docker-compose.yml

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    # will be remove if you run everything inside container
    root /var/www/html/public;

    # will be remove if you run everything inside container
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name {{getenv "NGINX_SERVER_NAME"}};

    server_tokens off;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    # will be remove
    # location / {
    #     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    # }

    # Add this, now nginx only redirect request to expose socket from docker
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:5050
        proxy_ser_header    X-Served-By Bitpress.io;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    # will be remove if you run everything inside container
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # will be remove if you run everything inside container
    add_header X-Served-By Bitpress.io;

    include h5bp/basic.conf;
}
```

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    image: test
    container_name: site
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-tier
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      # - /absolute/path/better:/var/www/html
    environment:
      APP_ENV: local
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app

  scheduler:
    image: test
    container_name: scheduler
    networks:       # <-- add thisadd this
      - app-tier    # <-- add thisadd this
    depends_on:
      - app
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      # - /absolute/path/better:/var/www/html
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: scheduler

  queue:
    image: test
    container_name: queue
    networks:       # <-- add thisadd this
      - app-tier    # <-- add thisadd this
    depends_on:
      - app
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      # - /absolute/path/better:/var/www/html
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: queue
```

---

You may have an issues between `env_file:` and `CONTAINER_ROLE` who have the priority: your 3 containers share the shame `.docker.env` it may be an issues. it may be a good idead to have:

```
.docker.app.env
.docker.scheduler.env
.docker.queue.env
```

Comment: Thank you for hour help, i've forgott a Dockerfile line xD